# Reclassify a raster based on 2 rasters

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have two rasters (`r1` and `r2`) in R with the same spatial extent and I'd like to create a raster (`r3`) that is conditional on values in `r1` and `r2`. I can set up a matrix and use `raster::reclassify`, but I can only make this work using one of the rasters. I'm looking for an efficient way to do this on the two rasters. For example (see below) if `r1 = 0` and `r2 < 2`, `r3 = 0.5`, but if `r1 = 1` and `r2 < 2`, `r3 = .8`. Then if `r1 = 0` and `r2 > 2`, `r3 = 0.7`, but if `r1 = 1` and `r2 > 2`, `r3 = .9` (I have several more conditions that I'd like to use on the real data). Here is that example in code form.

```
    library(raster)
    # create two random rasters
    r1 <- raster(matrix(rbinom(16, size=1, prob=.5), nrow=4))
    r2 <- raster(matrix(rpois(16, 2), nrow=4))
    # check that spatial extent is the same
    extent(r1) == extent(r2)

    # here is a reclassify matrix if r1==1
    reclass_m1 <- matrix(
      c(0,2,.8,
        3,5,.9
     ), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE
    )
    # reclassify matrix if r1==0
    reclass_m0 <- matrix(
      c(0,2,.5,
        3,5,.7
      ), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE
    )

    # so if r1==1,  I would want 
    r3 <- reclassify(r2, reclass_m1)

    # if r1==0, I would want 
    r3 <- reclassify(r2, reclass_m0)
    # but I want a single r3 that does this process consistently.
```

I looked at other similar questions and I didn't find exactly the solution I was looking for. I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `r1` and `r2` are comparable, you can just use logical indexing. This might get a bit tedious if you have a ton (or a varying amount) of conditions, but for this example it certainly works:

```
library(raster)
# create two random rasters
r1 <- raster(matrix(rbinom(16, size=1, prob=.5), nrow=4))
r2 <- raster(matrix(rpois(16, 2), nrow=4))
# check that spatial extent is the same
extent(r1) == extent(r2)

plot(r1)
plot(r2)

# create r3 from r1
r3 <- raster(r1)

# fill based on conditions

r3[r1 == 0 & r2 < 2] <- 0.5
r3[r1 == 1 & r2 < 2] <- 0.8
r3[r1 == 0 & r2 > 2] <- 0.7
r3[r1 == 1 & r2 > 2] <- 0.9


r3

# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 4, 4, 16  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 0.7, 0.8  (min, max)
```

Comment: Thank you @Val! This works for the simulated data. I'm having issues with my really big rasters, so I'm waiting to see if it works on them, but it should. One can avoid some of the tediousness by creating vectors defining the values of interest and then indexing within a loop.

Comment: @mikey If you rasters are really big, you could implement a block-wise solution

Comment: Update: I got this to work with the big rasters without going block-wise. For reference, the rasters are 30x30 m resolution for all of North America. Using logical indexing following @Val's solution above took about 30 minutes on a slow laptop (8 GB Ram).