# Raster logical indexing range of values

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have two rasters (`r1` and `r2`) and would like to reclassify them to a new raster (`r3`) conditional on the values in `r1` and `r2`.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674917/reclassify-a-raster-based-on-2-rasters?answertab=active#tab-top) had an excellent answer showing how to reclassify based on whole numbers. I would like to take this a stage further and learn how to reclassify across a range of values.

From Val's answer linked above:

```
library(raster)
# create two random rasters
r1 <- raster(matrix(rbinom(16, size=1, prob=.5), nrow=4))
r2 <- raster(matrix(rpois(16, 2), nrow=4))
r3 <- raster(r1)

# fill based on conditions
r3[r1 == 0 & r2 < 2] <- 0.5
r3[r1 == 1 & r2 < 2] <- 0.8
r3[r1 == 0 & r2 > 2] <- 0.7
r3[r1 == 1 & r2 > 2] <- 0.9
```

As an example, how can I reclassify such that if `r1` >0 but less than 2 **AND** `r2` is >0 but <2?

Comment: To answer your example: `r1 > 0 & r1 < 2 & r2 > 0 & r2 < 2` - does that answer your question as well?

Comment: Hi Val, thank you for the reply. To confirm, this works as expected, thank you. I didn't realised you could "chain" such commands together (i.e. `r1 > 0 & r1 <2`). I thought (for some reason) that the raster object could only be called once in such a command.

Comment: Conceptually, you can think as each condition giving you a boolean raster ... Then you chain them together, and only pixels which have only `TRUE` values, are reclassified. An interesting addition to your question would be, how to do this for a set of numbers, rather than a range.